# How i go about doing a key function with bootstrapvue rather than having long html codes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to make the following code shorter:
This is my attempt:

```
 <b-col class="border">

  <b-container class="text-center center container-fluid">
              <b-list-group cols="4" horizontal="md" class="row pl-3 flex-fill">
        <b-list-group-item
          rounded
          button
          class="col shadow-sm rounded mr-2"
          v-for="n in 20"
        :key="n"
        cols="4"
        rows="6"
      >
                  </b-list-group-item>
      </b-list-group>
          </b-container>

</b-col>
<b-col class="border" cols="6" md="4">
```

**I really don't want to go the route of having a lot of codes(Currently I am repeating the below codes 4 times there must be an easier way of doin this:**
[![What am trying to achieve][1]][1]
[![What am getting when trying to condense code][2]][2]

```
    <b-row class="text-center center row container-fluid">
      <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row pl-4 flex-fill">
        <b-list-group-item
          rounded
          button
          class="col shadow-sm rounded mr-2"
        >
          <div class="text-left">Chicken Foot Soup</div>
          <div class="text-right">$2,000</div>
        </b-list-group-item>
        <b-list-group-item button class="col mr-2 rounded border-left"
          >Dapibus ac facilisis in</b-list-group-item
        >
        <b-list-group-item button class="col mr-2 rounded border-left"
          >Morbi leo risus</b-list-group-item
        >
        <b-list-group-item button class="col mr-2 rounded border-left"
          >Cras justo odio</b-list-group-item
        >
        <b-list-group-item button class="col mr-2 rounded border-left"
          >Cras justo odio</b-list-group-item
        >
      </b-list-group>
    </b-row>
```

What am trying to achieve:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz5eX.png
what I got:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSAoG.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your items text in an array, then loop through that array using `v-for`. If your rows are identical, then your code should be something like this:

**Template**

```html
<div>
    <b-row
    v-for="n in 5"
    :key="`row${n}`"
    class="text-center center row container-fluid"
  >
    <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row pl-4 flex-fill">
      <b-list-group-item
        v-for="(item, key) in list"
        :key="key"
        button
        class="col mr-2 rounded"
      >
        <template v-if="item.left">
          <div class="text-left">{{ item.left }}</div>
          <div class="text-right">{{ item.right }}</div>
        </template>
        <span v-else> {{ item }} </span>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data: () => ({
    list: [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],
  }),
};
```

However, if the list items are different, then you will need a multidimensional array in order to achive your requirement. Try this:

**Template**

```html
<div>
    <b-row
     v-for="(row, n) in list"
    :key="`row${n}`"
    class="text-center center row container-fluid"
  >
    <b-list-group horizontal="md" class="row pl-4 flex-fill">
      <b-list-group-item
        v-for="(item, key) in row"
        :key="`item${key}`"
        button
        class="col mr-2 rounded"
      >
        <template v-if="item.left">
          <div class="text-left">{{ item.left }}</div>
          <div class="text-right">{{ item.right }}</div>
        </template>
        <span v-else> {{ item }} </span>
      </b-list-group-item>
    </b-list-group>
  </b-row>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    list: [
    [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],    [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],    [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],    [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],    [
      { left: "Chicken Foot Soup", right: "$2,000" },
      "Dapibus ac facilisis in",
      "Morbi leo risus",
      "Cras justo odio",
      "Cras justo odio",
    ],
    ],
  }),
};
```

Comment: Thanks Liro this works. My quick question to you however. Is how I add for variant to be chosen in script?
variant="`Variant${key}`"?

Comment: is it :variant=''variant"?

Comment: Id say depends on how you plan to style your list.

Comment: I want to be able to change it in get data.. so how do I it the v-for code to insert the variant?

Comment: Do you want to set different variant for each row or each column?

Comment: I thought we could set it for specific list.. but i would want to do it for each row...

Comment: Put all  variants you want in an array `myVariants: ["primary", "secondary", ....]` and in your `b-list-group-item` add this line `:variant="myVariants[n-1]"` for the first script or  `:variant="myVariants[n]"` for the second script. Make sure `myVariants` array size is as equal as rows number.

Comment: can you update the codes, as i try several iteration of what you said, and its not working for me. Thanks again.